# How to get values from lists of lists and add them to smaller lists

Tags: python

Say I have some lists like so:

```
myList1 = [1,2,3]
myList2 = [7,8,9]
myList3 = [13,14,15]
```

And I append them to a larger list:

```
myBigList = []
myBigList.append(myList1)
myBigList.append(myList2)
myBigList.append(myList3)
```

And now I have smaller lists like such:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

How would I iterate through my 'myBigList' list, and pull out the first value of all the smaller lists and store those values in A, the second values of all my shorter lists, in B, and the shorter of all the third in c? I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 3):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is great.

```
>>> myList1 = [1,2,3]
>>> myList2 = [7,8,9]
>>> myList3 = [13,14,15]
>>> myBigList = []
>>> myBigList.append(myList1)
>>> myBigList.append(myList2)
>>> myBigList.append(myList3)
>>> myBigList
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [13, 14, 15]]
>>> a, b, c = zip(*myBigList)
>>> a
(1, 7, 13)
>>> b
(2, 8, 14)
>>> c
(3, 9, 15)
```

Are you using `myBigList` for something? If you want, you can arrive at `a`, `b`, and `c` without putting them into `myBigList` at all.

```
>>> a, b, c = zip(myList1, myList2, myList3)
>>> a
(1, 7, 13)
>>> b
(2, 8, 14)
>>> c
(3, 9, 15)
```

Comment: mmmm...I really did miss that !

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [x[0] for x in myBigList]
b = [x[1] for x in myBigList]
c = [x[2] for x in myBigList]
```

EDIT: more efficient and optimized solution

```
a,b,c = [[x[i] for x in myBigList] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: This is O(n) in terms of how much code you have to write per `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, absolutely agree, but doesn't the OP want them separated?...I mean like separate variables?

Comment: Yes, but this still isn't necessary.

Comment: Note that each line differs by one character, and that character starts at `0` and increments by one with every line. That should suggest some refactoring you could do.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I think I've came up with something better